# Symfony multiple optional files with UploadedFile

Tags: symfony, file-upload, symfony-forms

I found a really good [article](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/07/manage-multiple-files-upload-in-symfony/) for adding multiple file uploads to my project, however I am trying to make the file uploads optional.

If I edit my document it will fail with the following error if I don't include a file.

Not sure what is a good work around for this issue. Any suggestions much appreciated.

**Error:**

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Entity\Cause::setFiles() must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, null given, called
>   in

This is my upload method for my **Cause** document

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreFlush()
 */
public function upload()
{

    foreach($this->uploadedFiles as $uploadedFile)
    {
        $file = new Imagefile();

        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$uploadedFile->guessExtension();
        $url1 = $this->getUploadDir();
        $path = "/".$url1."/".$filename;

        $file->setPath($path);
        $file->setSize($uploadedFile->getClientSize());
        $file->setName($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());

        $uploadedFile->move($this->getUploadDir(), $path);

        $this->getFiles()->add($file);
        $file->setCause($this);


        unset($uploadedFile);
    }
}


-- Setter --

    /**
     * Add files
     * @param UploadedFile $files
     */
    public function setFiles(uploadedFile $files)
    {

        $this->uploadedFiles[] = $files;        
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: try to change your `setFiles` method to: `public function setFiles($files = array())` because your `$files` property in `Cause` entity will be an array of `UploadedFile` objects when you submit the form with some files, else it should be an empty array.

Comment: I changed setFiles to the following and got the error below. no errors now if I don't attach a file but if I attach 1 file then I get the error.<br>

    /**
     * Add files
     * 
     */
    public function setFiles(array $files = null)
    {

        $this->uploadedFiles[] = $files;        
        return $this;
    }
<br>
--- error --
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Cause::setFiles() must be of the type array, object given, called in

<br>

Comment: remove `array` typing because `$files` variable can be an object or an array: `public function setFiles($files = null)`, and `public function setFiles($files = array())` didn't work ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `setFiles` method to:

```
public function setFiles($files = null)
```

because your `$files` property in `Cause` entity can be an object of instance `UploadedFile` or an array of `UploadedFile` objects or null value, when you submit the form.